# Complex join for selecting two subjects only

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am doing one project in MySQL. I have one problem with a `join`.

```
+---+-----------+-----------+
|id | name      | elective  |
+---+-----------+-----------+
| 1 | Jone      | Math      |
| 2 | Jane      | Math      |
| 3 | Doe       | Math      | 
| 4 | Bloggs    | Math      |
| 5 | Peter     | Math      | 
| 6 | Chris     | Math      | 
| 7 | Mark      | Math      | 
| 3 | Doe       | Physics   | 
| 4 | Bloggs    | Physics   |
| 5 | Peter     | Physics   | 
| 6 | Chris     | Physics   | 
| 7 | Mark      | Physics   | 
| 5 | Peter     | Chemistry | 
| 6 | Chris     | Chemistry | 
| 7 | Mark      | Chemistry | 
+---+-----------+-----------+
```

In the above table few persons have chosen more than two subjects and few others only two subjects. And others have chosen only one subject.

But I want to display only the second one, i.e. persons who have taken two subjects only. This I want to get using an inner join.

Comment: Why would someone ruin a nice edit of mine? It now looks terrible.

Comment: Please fix the table structure. The data can be interpreted in more than 1 way :(

Answer (score 3):

```
select id, name from tablename
group by id, name
having count (elective) = 2
```

---

Using only `joins` like OP requested:

```
select t1.id, t1.name
from tablename t1
inner join tablename t2 on t2.id = t1.id and t2.name = t1.name and t2.name <> t1.name
left outer join tablename t3 on t3.id = t2.id and t3.name <> t1.name and t3.name <> t2.name
where t3.name is null
```

Tables `t1` and `t2` select two different `electives` for the same `id/person`. Table `t3` will select another `elective`. When I put in the `where` clause that I want the `t3.name` to be `NULL` it means that it doesn't exist a third `elective` different from the ones previous selected.

If exists a third one the `where` clause will remove those `names`.

The two `inner joins` are present to `select` at least two different `electives`.

Comment: And no offence, but your query won't work either, because there can be two persons with the same name.

Comment: Glad we agreed that the table structure is terrible and needs fixing.

Comment: By the way, just put another `6 Mark Math` into the table and your query is destroyed :) You need to be grouping on id's and not on person's names. It makes no sense.

Comment: Now that I see, your query is correct. He has the same id for the same person.

Comment: @balamurugan why do you want that way?

Comment: Quite a lot of confusion happened :) Glad we sorted out peacefully hehe :)

Comment: I saw an `id` and `mysql` and automatically though `AUTOINCREMENT` :P

Comment: @balamurugan only with `joins` like requested.

Comment: Yeah, aF, I think that does the job now as requested with joins only :) Still, the answer could be much simpler if the structure of the tables was correct :) But I am impressed that you took the time to finish it up :) Good job :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, name, COUNT(elective) FROM table GROUP BY id, name HAVING COUNT(elective) = 2
```

Comment: Well, it is the problem of the person who made the table, which doesn't fit class 3 of DB structure and should be rethought immediately. It obviously should hold only `person_id, subject_id` and have foreign keys.

Comment: Yours is more incorrect than mine, yet I get the minuses because I have a lower reputation. Seems fair :/

Comment: what do you think of my new query :P